# Hadoop CapacitySchueduler not using excess capacity

Tags: hadoop

I'm running the Hadoop CapacityScheduler with multiple queues and multiple users. I have three queues with capacities 70%, 20% and 10% respectively e.g.

`mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.default.capacity=70`

For all the queues the I have

`mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.default.maximum-capacity=100`

I was surprised to find that the queues hardly ever seemed to use their excess capacity (they would all "max out" at their queue-specific capacity) even though excess capacity was available. I later discovered that the queues would make use of excess capacity only if they contained jobs from multiple users.

I.e. any number of jobs submitted to a queue by a single user will never make user of excess capacity. Only if a second job is submitted by a different user will the excess capacity be used.

I would like a single user to use all cluster resources if there are no other jobs taking up any resources.

I have studied the CapacityScheduler documentation thoroughly and played around with the properties with no success.

Please if anyone knows how to do this let me know.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question, I have the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the property "mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue-name.user-limit-factor" in http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/capacity_scheduler.html.

By default, this value is set to 1 which ensures that a single user can never take more than the queue's configured capacity irrespective of how idle the cluster is. You can set it to be a larger number to achieve what you want.